# returning array from function in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-assignment, soundcloud

so I come from a heavy python background, and I'm trying to wrap my head around javascript. Here I have a function that returns an array of track IDs for soundcloud songs by the artist 'v-2-followers'. How would I go about assigning the output of SC.get(stuff) to a variable to reuse the track list in another function. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental. I'm less looking for an answer that explains how to do this, but more **why** it's done like that.

That said I would also very much appreciate the how. :)

```
(function() {

    SC.initialize({
        client_id:'__CLIENTID__';
    });

    // Would like to set a variable equal to the output of
    SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'v-2-followers' }, function(tracks) {
        trackIdList = [];
        tracks.forEach(function(track){
            trackIdList.push(track.id);
        });
        return trackIdList;
    });

    // And use the variable here.
    SC.stream('/tracks/'+trackIdList[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)], function(sound) {
        sound.play();
        sound.pause();
        $('#fabrizio').hover(function(e){
            sound.resume();
        }, function(e){
            sound.pause();
        });
    });
})();
```

I can see that I'm missing something fundamental about variable assignment and scope, or function callbacks here. I've exhausted myself skimming docs on the subject. If anyone can tell me how to do this, and more importantly, why it's done that way, for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `trackIdList` as a global variable because it is not created using `var`.  So as it is, you can already access it from any other function.  If you wanted to limit its scope to just the outer function, add `var trackIdList;` as the first line of your function.  You should be declaring variables with `var` everywhere in order to limit their scope.

```
(function() {
    var trackIdList;
    ...
})();
```

Further reading:  [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

The other concept you need to understand is regarding asynchronous execution and callbacks in JavaScript.  Your code that populates `trackIdList` is contained within a callback function which is (most likely) called *after* your call to `SC.stream()`.  If `SC.stream()` depends on the value of `trackIdList`, it should be called from the callback function.

It may help to illustrate what's going on by separating out your callback functions.

```
(function () {
    var trackIdList = [];

    SC.initialize({
        client_id: '__CLIENTID__'
    });

    SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'v-2-followers' }, processTracks);

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackIdList[randomIndex], processSound);

    function processTracks(tracks) {
        tracks.forEach(function (track) {
            trackIdList.push(track.id);
        });
    }

    function processSound(sound) {
        sound.play();
        sound.pause();
        $('#fabrizio').hover(function (e) {
            sound.resume();
        }, function (e) {
            sound.pause();
        });
    }
})();
```

`SC.get()` makes an asynchronous request and returns immediately.  Then `SC.stream()` is called *without waiting for the request to return*. `processTracks()` isn't called until the request comes back.  The trouble is that `SC.stream()` depends on `processTracks()`, but is called immediately.  To fix this, call `SC.stream()` from the callback function of `SC.get()`:

```
(function () {
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: '__CLIENTID__'
    });

    SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'v-2-followers' }, processTracks);

    function processTracks(tracks) {
        var trackIdList = [];
        tracks.forEach(function (track) {
            trackIdList.push(track.id);
        });

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
        SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackIdList[randomIndex], processSound);
    }

    function processSound(sound) {
        sound.play();
        sound.pause();
        $('#fabrizio').hover(function (e) {
            sound.resume();
        }, function (e) {
            sound.pause();
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: without var, it means "scope of this" which in the case of the web is window (or global), in node it's the scope of the current file.

Comment: wrapping it in the scope of your closure (the function) as gilly3 suggests, is a good practice & keeps your scopes neater.

Comment: I see, so because myVar was initialized globally, if I change it's value inside of a function, it's myVar=myValue only inside of that function. So when I call it with the next function, it looks up to the next scope, which is global, where myVar equals whatever it did when it was initialized.. Globally. And, I see what your saying, that I need to get any input I'll need for the async functions ready **before** I call any async functions. That just seems so obvious in retrospect.

Comment: No. A variable declared globally certainly can be reassigned within a function. Now, a function can have a variable whose name is the same as a higher scoped variable.  This is accomplished by using the `var` keyword to declare the variable within the function.  It effectively hides the higher scoped variable from the function.  It sounds like you are trying to read the variable before the callback has been executed and populated the variable.

Comment: @askthewolves - I've edited my answer to elaborate on the asynchronous aspect, which is what sounds like is the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain one way - with callbacks.  The reason people do it this way is that there are synchronous operations, and asynchronous operations.  In your case, you need to perform an AJAX request - we don't know how long it will take for `SC.get` to finish, and we don't want the program to hang while we wait for it.  So instead of waiting, we tell it "go get those tracks, and I'm passing you a function to call when you are done.  In the meantime, I'm going to go on ahead with the rest of the program."

```
(function() {

  SC.initialize({
    client_id:'__CLIENTID__'
  });

  var getTracks = function(callback) {
    SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'v-2-followers' }, function(tracks) {
        trackIdList = [];
        tracks.forEach(function(track){
            trackIdList.push(track.id);
        });
        callback(trackIdList);
    });
  }

  // And use the variable here.
  var stream = function(trackIdList) {
    SC.stream('/tracks/'+trackIdList[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)], function(sound) {
        sound.play();
        sound.pause();
        $('#fabrizio').hover(function(e){
            sound.resume();
        }, function(e){
            sound.pause();
        });
     });
   }
   getTracks(stream);
 })();
```