# Javascript - asynchronous operations with soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, soundcloud

Here is the code:

```
var holder;
var findSong;
var embedHolder;


$(".hypemList ol").on('click','li',function (){

   holder = $(this).text();
   findSong = SC.get('/tracks', { q: holder });
   embedHolder = findSong._result[0].uri;
   SC.oEmbed(embedHolder // song to embed
      , { color: "ff0066"
      , auto_play: false
      , maxwidth: 500
      , maxheight: 1000
      , show_comments: true  // options
    , element: document.getElementById("soundTest") // what element to attach player to
  });

});
```

What I would like to happen:

I have a list of songs that I would like to play.  When I click on the song, I will grab that string and then search `soundcloud API` using that string.  I will take index 0 of the result and place that in `SC.oEmbed` to play the song.

When I open dev console, I get this error when I click on a song --

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_result' of undefined.

I believe I need to wait for `findSong` to finish and then I can use `embedHolder` and place that into `SC.oEmbed`.

What I have done:

I found this: [returning array from function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644740/returning-array-from-function-in-javascript).  I tried following what they did, but it didn't seem to work.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction on what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

SC.get() has 3 parameters: the path, the options and *the callback*. The callback is a function that will be called once `SC.get` is done. The callback in this case takes the array of results as a parameter. Using the callback in your code will look like this:

```
 SC.get('/tracks', { q: holder }, function(tracks){ 
        embedHolder = tracks[0].uri;
        SC.oEmbed(embedHolder // song to embed
          , { color: "ff0066"
          , auto_play: false
          , maxwidth: 500
          , maxheight: 1000
          , show_comments: true  // options
        , element: document.getElementById("soundTest") // what element to attach     player to
      });

});
```

Hope it helps!